# endless loop in webkits, may be htaccess conflict

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

Got flamer script (http://provenlogic.xyz/flamer) installed and configured but start to get problem just in Opera and Chrome (in Firefox and IE works fine).

Here is my installation http://chronogym.com/flamer

The same url causes endless loop in Chrome and Opera and works fine in FF.

First question is how it could depend on browser, because I thought that redirections are driven only by server side.

Another question: when adding something like dd('test'); somewhere in controller even in FF script begins to brake connection instead of showing dumping result.

Project is placed in subdir on server: root/flamer. In root I got other project. I suggest that .htacces from that project can cause problems or conflicting with .htaccess from flamer but can't find out the exact cause.

root .htaccess

```html
ModPagespeed off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Options +FollowSymlinks
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(_css|_js|memberarea)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

   RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.chronogym.com


RedirectPermanent /coaching.php   http://chronogym.com/2-0-coaching_minceur.html
```

subdir .htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.chronogym.com/flamer/$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://chronogym.com/flamer$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middle rule is not correct but that would conflict anyway. You need to use `RewriteBase` if this .htaccess file is in the `flamer` folder. Have your rules like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /flamer/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.chronogym.com/flamer/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://chronogym.com/flamer$1 [R=301,L]

was added later, and I agree it has to be removed. Also added RewriteBase /flamer/ and see that pages began to show something at least but endless loop takes place all the same.